# how to get the height of a browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question regarding the code below which I grabbed from:

http://jsfiddle.net/SAFX/Mq52k/16/

I am more of a low level programmer, so I know enough HTML/CSS just to get by. I am trying to figure out how to set the table height based on the browser window height instead of a fixed value of 150px. With my limited knowledge of css, I am assuming this may not be possible with css alone? Would something like java script be required?

HTML:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table table-condensed" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

<div class="div-table-content">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>more data</td>
                <td>hello world, nice to see you again, and what a beautiful fixed header
                    column you have</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >data</td>
                <td >more data</td>
                <td >hello world, nice to see you again, and what a beautiful fixed header
                    column you have</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >data</td>
                <td >more data</td>
                <td >hello world, nice to see you again, and what a beautiful fixed header
                    column you have</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >data</td>
                <td >more data</td>
                <td >hello world, nice to see you again, and what a beautiful fixed header
                    column you have</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >data</td>
                <td >more data</td>
                <td >hello world, nice to see you again, and what a beautiful fixed header
                    column you have</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >data</td>
                <td >more data</td>
                <td >hello world, nice to see you again, and what a beautiful fixed header
                    column you have</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.div-table-content {
  height:150px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: That is definitely possible with browsers that support viewport units (i.e. those that support CSS3 specs). For viewport height, you can use `100vh` (means 100% of the viewport height).

Comment: I agree with Terry, let CSS handle the styling. no need for javascript with this one.

Comment: sweet, nice and simple. put it to an answer for the win

Comment: But why do you even want to give height if you want to fit it on whole screen, just remove height, it will automatically take as per content and rows available.

Comment: Trying to have a scrollable table without the header of the table scrolling. It makes the data displayed more readable

Comment: Might be useful: https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my original comment, you can use [viewport units in browsers that support CSS3 specs for this new unit of measurement](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units). The support is pretty widespread as of now, with 84% of browsers supporting it. Partial support is not an issue for you, since you're not using the `vmax` unit :)

Therefore, for a table to occupy 100% of the viewport height, simply use `100vh`, which means 100% of viewport height. By definition, each unit represents 1% of the axis of measurement.

For usability issues, you might want to consider declaring a minimum height, too, so that the table does not collapse to a ridiculously small height when the user viewport is too short.

In the code snippet below, I have given your `.div-table-content` a full viewport height, in conjunction with a minimum height of 250px. You can resize your viewport to see it in action. I have added a yellow background colour to the element for illustration purposes.

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.div-table-content {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table table-condensed" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

<div class="div-table-content">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>more data</td>
                <td>hello world, nice to see you again, and what a beautiful fixed header
                    column you have</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >data</td>
                <td >more data</td>
                <td >hello world, nice to see you again, and what a beautiful fixed header
                    column you have</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >data</td>
                <td >more data</td>
                <td >hello world, nice to see you again, and what a beautiful fixed header
                    column you have</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >data</td>
                <td >more data</td>
                <td >hello world, nice to see you again, and what a beautiful fixed header
                    column you have</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >data</td>
                <td >more data</td>
                <td >hello world, nice to see you again, and what a beautiful fixed header
                    column you have</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >data</td>
                <td >more data</td>
                <td >hello world, nice to see you again, and what a beautiful fixed header
                    column you have</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the height in javascript by using:

**window.innerHeight**

Now when you want to allot height to a particular class you may use:

```
document.getElementsByCalssName('div-table-content')[0].style.height = window.innerHeight+"px";
```

**NOTE**

```
window.innerHeight
```

gives you the height of the window in integer you can apply changes in it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `height:100vh` in your `CSS`. here is your [updated fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mq52k/1175/)